# Webview doesn't return his place after typing in input field

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I'm working on some iPhone application that contain a webview with these properties:

```
[[webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setScrollEnabled:NO];  //to stop scrolling

[[webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setBounces:NO]; //to stop bouncing
```

On the webview there is a text input
The problem is that after I'm trying to type an input, the keyboard is rising and all the page too. but after the keyboard is down the page itself stay upwards.

[image: example]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bY7B.png)

Because the webview is without scrolling it can't be possible to see the page correctly until I restart the app.

any ideas?

Comment: The solution I've found is: onblur="window.location = '#'"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution. First add this line of code in your `- (void)viewDidLoad` of your view controller:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) 
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

This is so you get notified when the keyboard hides.

Add the following method to your view controller:

```
- (void)keyboardDidHide: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    UIScrollView* scroll = nil;

    if([webView respondsToSelector: @selector(scrollView)])
        scroll = webView.scrollView; //iOS5 and up
    else
        scroll = [webView.subviews objectAtIndex:0]; //iOS4 and below

    [scroll setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0, 0)];
}
```

This will cause your UIWebView to scroll to 0, 0 (top) whenever the keyboard is hidden.